# Changing of the limits of integration with the integral metric.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Consider the following sequence of functions,

$$f_n(x) =
\begin{cases}
nx  & \text{for $0\le x \le \frac1n$} \\
1 & \text{for $x\ge \frac1n$}
\end{cases}$$

And call to mind the integral metric on the space of continuous functions, $C([0,1])$

$$d_{int}(f,g)=\int_{0}^1 |f(x)-g(x)|\,dx$$

With $f$ and $g$ continuous functions contained therein.

Setting $f(x):=1$ and moving to show that $f_n \to f$ in the metric space $(C([0,1]),d_{int})$, I have the following in my notes:

$$d_{int}(f_n,f)=\int_{0}^1 |f_n(x)-1|\,dx$$

$$=\int_{0}^{1/n} (1-nx)\,dx$$

Why is it that the upper limit of integration has changed?

Comment: Since you want the integral of **f_n(x)-1** instead of **f(x)-1**, and then we have that **f_n(x)-1=0** outside **[0,1/n]**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_0^1\vert f_n(x)-1\vert dx=\int_0^{1/n}\vert f_n(x)-1\vert dx+\int_{1/n}^1\vert f_n(x)-1\vert dx$

Since $f_n(x)=1$ for $x\geq\frac{1}{n}$, the second term is equal to $0$. You can also remove the absolute value in the first term since for $0\leq x\leq\frac{1}{n}$, $f_n(x)=nx\leq 1$.

Comment: Makes much more sense now, thanks!